# How do I simplify complex integer powers of 1?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

In mathematica 4, when I enter

```
FullSimplify[(-1)^n + (-1)^{3n}, n ∈ Integers],
```

I get the desired result

> ```
> 2(-1)^n.
> ```

However, when I enter

```
 FullSimplify[1 + (-1)^n + (-1)^{3n}, n ∈ Integers],
```

it gives me

> `1 +(-1)^n + Cos[3 n π]$`

instead of the simpler `1 + 2(-1)^n`. I'm perplexed why it gives the simple version in one case and not the other.

Is there a way to get around it? I don't have `Refine`, so I don't know what result it gives in more recent versions. I am simplifying expressions that have many powers of $-1$ raised to the $a\,n$ power where $a$ can be various integers, and I am having to reduce each one by hand.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The answers you get are equivalent. `Cos[π] = -1`, `Cos[2π] = 1`, `Cos[3π] = -1`, `Cos[nπ] = (-1)^n`, `Cos[3nπ] =( -1)^3n`! Also, `(-1)^3n = ((-1)^2n)((-1)^n)  =  (-1)^n` . So if you use FullSimplify[] on your expression, it should yield the correct answer. Also, if you provide the main expression you are trying to simplify including your code, we can help you better. P.S. I have Mathematica 11.2.0 and I get your expected result `1 + 2(-1)^n`

Comment: I get `1 + 2(-1)^n` on v10.4 and v11.1.

Comment: Don't use list (curly) brackets for parentheses. Note that your result is a `List` rather than a scalar.

Comment: After having removed the curly braces, this works correctly for me returning  `1 + 2 (-1)^n`. MMa 11.2, Win7.

Comment: Bob Hanlon is right. do not use `{}` instead of `()`. `[]` is for functions, `{}` is for lists i.e. tables, arrays, vectors, matrices, etc. and `()` is for equations and expressions.